# Unable to download Ubuntu latest version

Tags: 11.04, 10.10, upgrade

I have Ubuntu 10.10 installed on my system. On update manager it is showing that new release 11.04 is available. But when I try to Upgrade Ubuntu it gives below message:

"Authentication Failed. Authenticating the upgrade failed. There may be problem with the network or server."

Answer (score 2):

> On update manager it is showing that new release 11.04 is available.

You can no longer upgrade via the network from 10.10 because it stopped being supported as of last month (April 2012). Your only option is an alternate upgrade.

## Upgrading Using the Alternate CD/DVD

- Download the alternate installation CD from http://releases.ubuntu.com/natty/
- Mount the ISO as a drive with a command like:

  ```
   `sudo mount -o loop ~/Desktop/ubuntu-11.04-alternate-i386.iso /media/cdrom0`
  ```
- A dialog will be displayed offering you the opportunity to upgrade using that CD.    Follow the on-screen instructions.
- If the upgrade dialog is not displayed for any reason, you may also run the following command pressing `Alt+F2`: `gksu "sh /cdrom/cdromupgrade"`

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu and Linux in general does not have the best track record regarding upgrades unless using LTS versions. So the best solution might be to save your data externally and then doing a fresh install of 12.04.